# How to remove a photo in background photos of one Windows 8 theme?

Tags: windows-8, themes, desktop-customization

As we can download [themes for Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/footpaths-download-theme), I have the need to remove one photo in one theme's background photo set.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**STEP1** Right click on desktop->Personalize

**STEP2** Click the theme you want to change

**STEP3** now click on **desktop background**

**STEP4** now **UNCHECK** the photo which u dont want!

**STEP5** click **save changes**.... DONE!

[image]

[image]

[image]